# How to change redirection way on very basic content restriction?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to change below code to redirect some external link rather than redirecting to login page. How can I do this?

```
    <?php
function vbcr_simple_content_restriction() {
    global $wp_query;
    if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if( is_category() || is_archive() || is_single() || is_tax() || is_tag() || is_feed() || is_comment_feed() || is_attachment() || is_search() ) {
            $option_redirect_to = get_option('redirect-to');
            if(empty($option_redirect_to)) {
                // retrieve WP login URL
                $option_redirect_to = wp_login_url();
            }
            $status = "302";
            wp_redirect( $option_redirect_to, $status ); exit;
        }
    }
    ob_flush();
}

function content_restriction_output_buffer() {
    // this is needed for the redirection
    ob_start();
```

As you can see it goes to wp login url:

```
$option_redirect_to = get_option('redirect-to');
            if(empty($option_redirect_to)) {
                // retrieve WP login URL
                $option_redirect_to = wp_login_url();
```

How can I change it to this link: https://example.com/external ?